# when I create archive the version number is automatically replace by some different string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have attached right certificate and profile but, when I do archive in version number replace with different string

Comment: can you share the replace version number string?

Comment: 9aa181272b474fde3590bf899b7617e68a141b1a

Answer (score 0):

Click on your xcodeproj file and go to info tab near build settings. Change bundle version number and bundle version string. Then archive.

Comment: I have added the version and build as 1.3.1

Comment: Not upload on appstore version is replace by above number

Answer (score 0):

check in xcodeproj settings->build phases if there is any script related to versioning